# Is there a way I can color the entire console (like setting the background color) using ANSI color codes?

Tags: c#

I have no issue with ANSI color codes and how they work but I have no idea how to exactly color the entire background with such color. I want to make it so that the entire background of the console changes to the ANSI color code. Is there a way I can do this?

The answer does not have to be the same on all platforms - I am looking for something that works for Windows.

I am talking about ANSI color coding. Something such as `Console.BackgroundColor = ...`  will not fit my needs because I need to use RGB values to color the entire console.

Doing something like printing out a background color code and then clearing the console makes unexpected behavior:

```cs
Console.Write(Marker.Background.FromRGB(127, 31, 217)); // Gets an ANSI color code for RGB values 127, 31 and 217
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

prints this out:

[image]

How can I get it so that the background color on the `Hello world!` is applied to the entire terminal?

This is not a duplicate. I am using ANSI color coding when all of the suggested duplicates use `Console.BackgroundColor = ...` which is not what I need.